# Which backend framework/API is suitable for secure access to database via intermediate layer for a multientity mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, backend

Can you recommend me a good backend for a mobile app + web frontend and a framework/API?
I want to make a mobile app that is multientity, so I don't want to have this app access a database directly, but rather via an intermediate layer providing some services. This way no one could reverse-engineer the app, get the database credentials and query the database at will.
I was rather thinking on an authentication service that would provide you a token or a couple of tokens, and using that token you could (via a REST/SOAP API) ask services to provide you with the information needed (and which you're allowed to use).

When I search for tutorials, all I see is basic app-to-database connections, but I was looking for a backend that could provide me this functionality.

If there were some services already available (authentication, token management, and so no, that would be a plus). I've seen Firebase (actually I use it to send push notifications to android and ios devices) but I fear it can get pricey. Any other recommendations?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a very common practice (app->server->db->server->app) flow. Why is your case different?

Comment: No, I guess it's not different but all the tutorials I've seen do app->db->app and I don't like that approach. So as I'm new here I was asking for framework recommendations

Comment: Usually when managing authentication and user data, as well as wanting to make the data synchronous across different devices, you use a backend server. Choosing the framework, programming language and more depends on many factors, such as previous knowledge, type of product, time constraints and more.

Comment: @gioravered, I know Java, C/C++, C# and PHP. Any recommendation?